# Is using DDL statements in ETL script right approach?

Tags: etl, data-warehouse, ddl, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm working on redesigning DWH solution previously based on Teradata with lots of BTEQ scripts performing transformations on mirror tables loaded from source DBs. New solutions will be based on Snowflake and as a transformation tool set of SQL (Snowflake) scripts is being prepared.

**Is that a right approach to use in ETL scripts DDL statements which create e.g. temporary table which than et the end of script is dropped?**

In my opinion such table should be created before running this script instead of creating it in the script on fly. One argument opts that DDL statements on Snowflake commits transaction and that's why I want to avoid DDL statements in transformation scripts. Please help me finding pros and cons of using DDL statements in ETL process and back me up that I'm right or convince that I'm wrong.

Answer (score 0):

If you are wanting transactions to cover all your SELECT/INSERT/MERGE steps of your transformation step of your ELT, you need to not create/drop any tables, as those will commit your open transactions.

We get around this by have pre-existing worker tables per task/deployment that are create/truncated prior to the transaction section of our ELT process. And our tooling does not allow a task to run at the same time.

Thus we load into a landing table, we transform into temporary tables, then we multi-table merge into the final tables. With only the last steps needing to be in transactions.